# How to pass variable to callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, scope

I have the following piece of code, and I'm not very clear on how to pass it all the way down to the onload function.

I have tried to define it in different places but without success, especially because its definition needs to happen in the function passed to the `document.on` method, since I want to get the hold of the `this` reference.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', "#someId", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var variable = $(this).attr('name');

        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
            type: 'openFile', accepts:[{
                extensions: ['txt']
            }] 
        }, 
        function(fileEntry) {
            if (!fileEntry) {
                return;
            }
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    ////******* how to access variable here? *******\\\\
                    chrome.storage.local.set({'txt': e.target.result});
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I need to access `variable` inside the `onload` function.
How can I pass it?

Comment: You don't need to pass it. It's in an outer scope, therefore naturally available in the scope chain.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, I am breakpointing inside the onload function and looking and the variable scope, and I can't see variable there. Also when I try to get the value in the console I get ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Comment: In that case, either I have misunderstood the question, or you are running different code from that which appears above.

Comment: Just a thought - try naming the var something other than `variable`. Javascript has a whole bunch of reserved words that don't actually appear in the language itself. `variable` may be one of these.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I have edited the code, everything is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(e)`, don't think that will make any difference though. Tried to change the variable name to something else than `variable`, nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure the `reader.onload` event fires?

Comment: Have you tried something according to my suggestion (using the `var` keyword in the `onload` scope)?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, yes because I'm debugging on the `chrome.storage.local` line

Comment: Then it remains a mystery why `variable` is not still available at the point you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) doing this :

```
onload = function () {
    var variable;
    $(document).on('click', "#someId", function(e) {
        variable = $(this).attr('name');
        // use variable here
    });
    // and here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I parse your code correctly, then you should be able to use variable where you want it. It is in correct scope and there is a closure which will keep it active.

Making it global, like in previous answer will generate issues with simultaneus calls - variable value maybe overwritten by next call and you will get different value when get to it in your .onload.

Comment: Sure, it does not guarantee the issues, it just allows them.

Comment: I just had nasty bugs with using global variables in onclick handlers. Since then I never do it, just as a rule to prevent such bugs in future

Comment: I am breakpointing inside the `onload` function and looking and the variable scope, and I can't see `variable` there. Also when I try to get the value in the console I get _ReferenceError: variable is not defined_